# How to add non-persistent field to form?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

There is SonataAdminBundle and `User` entity. Admin service for it:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('name')
        // ...
        ->add('send_greeting', 'checkbox')
    ;
}
```

Field `send_greeting` is not related to `User` entity. It required only for admin service (depends it value we would send email or not after saving user). So how it possible add this field to form without binding to entity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set `property_path` option to `false`. e.g

```
->add('send_greeting', 'checkbox',array(
   'property_path' => false
))
...
```

Answer (score 21):

With symfony 2.1 and above, use `mapped` instead of `property_path`. [(Symfony2 form reference)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#mapped)